# Flatten a Multilevel Doubly Linked List leetcode error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, linked-list

I don't understand why do you get error even when you try to just return head linked list that was given as an argument here is a question

430. Flatten a Multilevel Doubly Linked List
     Medium

Topics
Companies
You are given a doubly linked list, which contains nodes that have a next pointer, a previous pointer, and an additional child pointer. This child pointer may or may not point to a separate doubly linked list, also containing these special nodes. These child lists may have one or more children of their own, and so on, to produce a multilevel data structure as shown in the example below.

Given the head of the first level of the list, flatten the list so that all the nodes appear in a single-level, doubly linked list. Let curr be a node with a child list. The nodes in the child list should appear after curr and before curr.next in the flattened list.Return the head of the flattened list. The nodes in the list must have all of their child pointers set to null.

link to that question https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-a-multilevel-doubly-linked-list/description/

Even when you try to just return the argument you get this error:

Line 129 in solution.jsnode = node.next;^TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next')

for the life of me I don't understand why? the argument you are given is a node is it because child node was not set to null but you should not get error for that I don't know. if somebody can explain what is going on I will be very grateful.

Comment: *"Even when you try to just return the argument you get this error:"*: I just tried this and got no such error. So the only code to enter is  `var flatten = function(head) { return head; };` -> just wrong answers, but no errors.